# No sound through HDMI cable, nvidia

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, sound, hdmi

Few days ago I've decided to install Ubuntu 13.04 (with dual boot Windows 8) on my old laptop (Toshiba Qosmio f55 q502) and make it my media center.

Everything went well except that I don't have sound through my HDMI cable. I have tried looking for solution in other posts but with no luck. 
In the sound settings, I see 3 options: speakers, SPDIF, and HDMI. When I choose HDMI I'm not getting any sound in my TV.
I have updated the nvidia driver (before that there was no video through HDMI as well)

Please help me to solve this issue and to forget windows for good. 
Thank you

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC272 Analog [ALC272 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC272 Digital [ALC272 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you open a terminal and give me the output from

```
aplay -l
```

I had this problem in the past. I know SMPlayer can select audio outputs, so it might be worth checking out that app to see if you can get anything at all from your HDMI audio.

On SMPlayer, start up a video, then on the menu select *Tools* -> *Preferences*. On the Audio tab go for the Output Driver and change it from *Pulse* to one of the *alsa (0.x - HDA NVidia HDMI)* options. See what works.

Installing *pavucontrol* will also give you much better control over your individual audio outputs. HDMI output may be muted by default.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply.
I have tried your devices but with no luck.
In the SMPlayer i don't have any option with  HDMI or Nvidia. I do have  few "HDA Intel" but non of them gave sound to the TV when playing a movie.

Comment: In pavucontrol, I have selected "Digital Stereo (HDMI) output" but just cut the sound.
My output from aplay -l is

Comment: **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC272 Analog [ALC272 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC272 Digital [ALC272 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Answer (score 1):

OK... Let's try something different. Open a terminal for me and let me know if the following command makes a noise through your HDMI setup.

```
aplay -D hw:0,3 testsound.wav
```

NEW INSTRUCTIONS

Open a terminal and copy the command below

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Enter your password, and the configuration file for pulseaudio should open.

Look for:

```
load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=0
```

and add a # to the start so it reads:

```
# load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=0
```

Now go to the end of the file and add on a new line:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,3
```

Save the file and reboot. This should restart your system with the HDMI audio.

Comment: when runung "aplay -D hw:0,3 testsound.wav testsound.wav", this is what Iv'e got: No such file or directory

Comment: I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Actually... this is good news. If the HDMI channel wasn't working, you would have seen a different message. Your computer is ignoring the HDMI channel when you boot. It's possible to change this. Are you OK to change configuration files?

Comment: As I said, I'm totally new in this OS, but in windows I'm more then an average user. I don't have knowledge in writing codes but I can follow instructions. What should I do or read in order to change configuration files?

Comment: I'll change my answer...

Comment: I’ve followed the instructions. After doing so, my sound totally disappear. In sound settings-input, i have now only Built-in Audio, no HDMI and no optic outputs. in pavucontrol-playback, I can see that sound indicator bar moving when playing sound and in configuration I don't have anything.

Comment: in aplay -l the 3rd section changed from 1/1 to 0/1 
"card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1"

Comment: This worked for me. Used hw:1,7 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the HDMI audio is muted by default. Go into alsamixer and see if the HDMI channel is muted. Also your output of aplay -l shows only the integrated Intel Display and Audio driver, not the Nvidia one. from the aplay output card 0 is the Intel card, card 1 may be your Nvidia card. You can add the -c # parameter to specify the card # to work with.

try this in a console:

sudo alsamixer -c 1

Select the HDMI output and un-mute it if it is muted. It may just be that easy. If you don't see any devices remove the -c 1 and try again. If your HDMI audio out was already un-muted then there is a LOT of information out there on audio not playing over HDMI and it is quite a deep rabbit hole to go down.

You can also try this sound troubleshooting Procedure: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: Thank you for you help. In alsamixer I don't have HDMI, I have Master, Headphon, PCM, Mic, S/PDIF. The Chip is Nvidia MCP77/78 HDMI

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to go to Sounds Settings at the top right of the desktop, and select output: HDMI. This fixed the problem for me.

Just as reference aplay -l gives me the following:

```
 ****List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC1200 Analog [ALC1200 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC1200 Digital [ALC1200 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/364183/219564) has helped me:

Try the below code in terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.audio=1"
```

Run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart the system

Alternatively, and if this does not work, consider installing the proprietary driver for your ATI graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

The Xorg driver that Ubuntu selects can have issues with your particular audio device.  You may need to use one of the proprietary drivers to make sound work correctly.

Test - If you are having issues, make sure the HDMI device is selected in "Sound Settings" and click "Test Sound".  If you don't get sound from the "Front Left" and "Front Right" test buttons try this:

1. Go to Settings > Software & Updates > Proprietary Drivers and select the NVidia Legacy Driver (older cards) or the NVidia binary driver and click "Apply Changes."
2. Once the driver installation completes return to the "Sound Settings" again and repeat this test.  If it still doesn't work you can try a different driver.

I have to do this on my media center machine every time I reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: This issue has disappeared for me on Wiley.  FYI